# How to grant permissions for some role to execute custom Rules Components?

Tags: 7, rules, users, views

I created a view (table) and i asociated views bulk operations. I created 4 rules components. I have permissions only for `user/1` (admin). Another user role (eg. editor) can't see these options. "editor" user can see only "DELETE ITEM" rule components.

In permissions I have only the default actions (components); I created 4 new Rules Components, and these aren't displayed in `Admin > People > Permissions`.

Is there another method (trick) to give permissions for another role for custom Rules Components? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you **edit** the configuration of a custom Rules Component, within its `Settings`, there is an option with label ***Configure access for using this component with a permission*** (disabed by default). And with some additional explanation below it like so:

> By default, the action for using this component may be only used by users that have access to configure the component. If checked, access is determined by a permission instead.

If you enable this option (= add a checkmark), it'll display a table that looks similar to this one (whereas in this sample I only had a single custom role defined, i.e. "editor", and the label of my Rules Component is "ABC"):

```
!PERMISSION              !ANONYMOUS USER!AUTHENTICATED USER!ADMINISTRATOR!EDITOR!
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!Use Rules component ABC !      O       !         O        !       O     !   O  !
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you'd check (e.g) the checkbox below "Editor", then a user with role Editor would be allowed to execute the Rules Component ABC. And such user will also see it in the list of possible (allowed!) bulk operations in a VBO view (users without the required role will not be able to select it in such VBO view).

PS: user `user/1` is always considered as an exception to anything about permissions (so never consider that user as a reliable testcase for anything about permissions).

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled "Action permissions" check the role has permission to "Execute [action]" in `Admin > People > Permissions`

Comment: In permissions i have only the default actions (components); I created 4 new rules components, and these aren't displayed in Admin > People > Permissions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you know another method (trick) to give permissions for another role for custom rules components? Thank you.